# How to get value which function calculates while clicking on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, usecallback

I am clicking on a button , what It should do is trigger a function and add a new property inside object which is inside a large array of multiple objects, and eventually returns a new array , All I want to know is how we can use that new Array returned by that function ?

I am using this function to get triggered to change the array which I am passing it it, but I am not sure how I can get this value back. Sorry in advance for stupid question I am new to this.

```
const makeAdminPresenter = (collection) => {
        var newTiles = collection?.map( obj => {
            if(obj.userType === "administrator") {
                return {...obj, isAdminPresenting: true}
            }
            return obj;
        });
        console.log('pressed', newTiles)
        return newTiles

    };
    
    var newTiles = useCallback(() => {
         makeAdminPresenter(tiles);
    },[makeAdminPresenter, tiles]) 

    console.log('result',makeAdminPresenter,newTiles  )
```

I want to use newTiles, any suggestion ?

Comment: I am not really sure what the question is, are you clicking on a specific element in this array and what value do you want to return exactly?

Comment: I am clicking on a button , what It should do is trigger a function and add a new property inside object which is inside a large array of objects, and returns a new array , All I want to know is how we can use that new Array returned by that function ?

Answer (score 1):

in your code you should make use of states (using `useState` when having functional components) to store the state of the tiles. The `makeAdminPresenter` modifies the tiles and you will have to re-render the component after the tiles are updated. The code snippet below has an example on how this could be done:

```
export default function Page() {
    const [tiles, setTiles] = React.useState([...]); // The tiles, you probably initialise elsewhere

    const makeAdminPresenter = () => {
        var newTiles = tiles.map(obj => {
            if (obj.userType === "administrator") {
                return {...obj, isAdminPresenting: true}
            }
            return obj;
        });
        console.log('pressed', newTiles)

        setTiles(newTiles); // Update the state so that the component gets re-rendered
    };

    console.log('result', makeAdminPresenter, tiles) // After the button is pressed tiles will be the new tiles
    return (<>
            <button onClick={makeAdminPresenter}></button>
            {tiles.map((tile, i) => (<TileComponent key={i} tile={tile}/>))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you this sounds perfect , although do you know if we can just have the video tiles be inside a useMemo that changes based on that button press ? is that possible ?

Comment: @Curious_guy, I'm not too familiar with useMemo however it doesn't seem like it is what you need here, the makeAdminPresenter operation does not seem like a heavy computation, which is what useMemo is made for. If you need to make an API call or such to let the server know, what I always do is setState after it's completed using either a .then or async await, hope this helps!